# Help verify $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Help verify this answer.  Determine the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}$$

I say the answer is $-4$ because what I did was took the highest $x$'s on both sides and divided them. So $\frac{20x^2}{-5x^2}$ and because the $x$'s cancel out so I can't use $\infty$ in place of $x$, I'm left with $-4$.

If anyone can verify that I got the right answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you are. Are you familiar with l'Hospital?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's fine. Formally, your expression is $\textstyle 20+{6\over x}+{4\over x^2}\over\textstyle {7\over x}-{6\over x^2}-5$. Take the limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$ of this form, and you'll see most terms tend to $0$, leaving $20/-5=-4$ as the limit.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We can use the "arithmetics of limit" theorem and get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{20+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}}{\frac7x-\frac{6}{x^2}-5}=-\frac{20}5=-4$$

Comment: The *procedure* you used gives the right answer. The *justification* that it does is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track. Note that for non-zero $x,$ we can rewrite $$\frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}=\cfrac{\frac{20x^2+6x+4}{x^2}}{\frac{7x-6-5x^2}{x^2}}=\cfrac{20+\frac6x+\frac4{x^2}}{\frac7x-\frac5{x^2}-5}.$$ The limit of the numerator on the far right as $x\to\infty$ is $20$ and the corresponding limit of the far-right denominator is $-5.$ Hence, since $x$ is eventually non-zero as we let $x$ grow without bound, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}=\frac{20}{-5}=-4,$$ as you said.

Answer (score 2):

We use l'Hospitals rule for proof:
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{20x^2 + 6x + 4}{-5x^2 + 7x - 6} & = \left [ \frac{\infty}{-\infty} \right ] \\
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{40x + 6}{-10x + 7} & = \left [ \frac{\infty}{-\infty} \right ] \\
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{40}{-10} & = -4
\end{align*}$$
The indeterminate Forms are necessary for l'Hospital to hold.

Comment: The numerator need not tend to $\infty$ in order to appeal to L'Hopital. There is a more elementary proof, as the comments show.

Comment: @DavidMitra Indeterminate also includes $$\frac{0}{0}$$ All other forms do not allow l'Hosptial.

Comment: The precise statment for the "infinite" version is: Suppose $f$, $g$ are differentiable and $g'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$. Suppose furthur that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=\pm\infty$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}=L$, then   $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x)\over g(x)}=L$. (It does not matter how $f$ behaves. Though most calculus texts don't point this out, this version can be found on the wiki page and various analysis texts, e.g. Bartle and Sherbert or baby Rudin.) I only point this out so that more people become aware of this (probably useless) fact.

Answer (score 0):

The key is *polynomial division*.$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{20x^2+6x+4}{7x-6-5x^2}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{20x^2+6x+4}{5x^2-7x+6}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}-4\frac{5x^2+\frac32x+1}{5x^2-7x+6}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-4+O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\\&=-4\end{align*}$$